# Nginx blocking Keystone.js admin assets

Tags: node.js, nginx, keystonejs

So, I've deployed my Keystone.js site. But the admin styles and a bunch of other assets under the admin route are not found.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mysite.com;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My node_modules directory permissions are: `drwxr-xr-x` which is equivalent to: 755

Comment: What version of Node are you using? There's [a known issue with v5.7.0 and up](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/2325) - it's fixed in the master branch, but I don't think the version on NPM has the fix yet.

Comment: This may be your issue then - is it possible to downgrade your server's Node version to 5.6.x?

Comment: No, I can't downgrade :(

Comment: I think you might want to post an issue on their Github then, see what they recommend. It sounds to me like your only options are to downgrade Node, or upgrade Keystone to the master branch version. This is one of the main things putting me off trying Keystone at the minute, you would think they'd push a fix to NPM :/